# Dart / Flutter Web: How to write a test that covers `kIsWeb == true`?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, testing, dart, flutter-web

I want to run a unit test that covers both possible cases, web and non-web deployment. The code for the class to be tested basically looks like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Text("I'm web");
    } else {
      return Text("I'm not web");
    }
  }
}
```

`kIsWeb` is a constant provided by Dart that determines if the application was compiled to run on the web.

My current test class implementation is only able to test the non-web path. Is there a way to create a test for the case of `kIsWeb == true`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run test like this:

> flutter test --platform chrome

Unfortunately this method may not work on some platforms ([issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44583) for Windows 10). **Flutter for web** is still in BETA.

More information is available [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/master/pkgs/test/doc/configuration.md).

Comment: Thank you for that, this actually works in a limited way as I would have to decide beforehand for which platform to test and can't run tests for all at the same time. Furthermore, the option `--platform chrome` unfortunately does not work together with the option `--coverage` which I was interested in most. See this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55437).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to test it directly from a StatelessWidget, but I can show you a way that makes use of some concepts of Clean Architecture. Basically, you want to decouple the UI (that is, your widgets) from pure logic. So, what I usually do is to have a class that handles the logic, like this:

```
class MyWidgetViewModel {
  /// Whether or not the current environment is web.
  /// Should only be overridden for testing purposes.
  /// Otherwise, defaults to [kIsWeb].
  @visibleForTesting
  bool isWeb = kIsWeb;
}
```

Here, I have wrapped the `kIsWeb` constant in another variable `isWeb`, which defaults to kIsWeb. This means that it can be reassigned at a later time and, moreover, it is only visible to test cases thanks to the annotation `@visibleForTesting`.

At this point, we can reference that class in the widget. I generally use Dependency Injection with either Provider or BLoC, but here, for the sake of simplicity, I'll just pass the ViewModel in the widget constructor.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyWidgetViewModel myViewModel;

  const MyWidget(this.myViewModel, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (myViewModel.isWeb) { //<- Here we use `isWeb` instead of `kIsWeb`
      return Text("I'm web");
    } else {
      return Text("I'm not web");
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, we can exploit the `isWeb` variable in the tests. Don't forget to pass an instance of `MyWidgetViewModel()` to your `MyWidget` during the setup of the variables.

```
test(
  'Test based on platform (is web or not).',
  () async {
    // Arrange (setup)
    ...
    final MyWidgetViewModel myViewModel = MyWidgetViewModel();
    myViewModel.isWeb = true; //<- Use this to assign the value you prefer
    ...


    // Assert (expect, verify)
    ...
  },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also add a constructor and attribute to your widget which you would decorate with `@visibleForTesting`. Something similar to:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isTestingForWeb;
  MyWidget({@visibleForTesting this.isTestingForWeb = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb || isTestingForWeb) {
      return Text("I'm web");
    } else {
      return Text("I'm not web");
    }
  }
}
```